# Nginx return 404 for base url but every other url works using dotnet and angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, nginx

I am trying to deploy a dotnet application with angular. However, when I am configuring nginx as the documentation by Microsoft recommends it, then accessing the website on the base url throws a 404 not found, but all other urls work fine.

My sites-available:

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    return   444;
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    listen        443 ssl;
    server_name   v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de *.supersrv.de;

    index /var/www/donau_lead_generator/donau-lead-generator/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/wwwroot/index.html;
    root /var/www/donau_lead_generator/donau-lead-generator/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/;
    location / {

        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

I am building using:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

If i access the /index.html it finds the index.html but if I access without it it returns 404 not found even though I redirect every url to index.html in my angular code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RewardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'reward', component: RewardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }   
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying different solutions I found here [1](https://hexquote.com/deploying-net-core-angular-and-postgres-web-application-on-ubuntu-nginx/) that one has to specify the nginx sites-available file like the following:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen        443 ssl;
    server_name   v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de *.v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de;


    location /reward {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/reward;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /person {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/person;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/{
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/index.html; -> this makes index page work but rest fails
        root /var/www/donau_lead_generator/donau-lead-generator/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/wwwroot;
        index index.html;

        # proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/v2202207178565194475.supersrv.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot
}
```

For every api endpoint one has to define the proxy pass but for the index / one has to serve the wwwroot folder.